# library to help user to interact with app at first launch

Tags: android, launch

I would like to help the user only at first launch in my Android app by following steps like Google does when you first boot a Nexus device :

[image]

I was wondering if such a library already exists... or do I need to create all of this by mylself ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there sure is! It's called [Showcase View](https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView/).